# Could not see hdf5 files while monitoring and saving keras modeli using ModelCheckPoint

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

i am running keras model and indicating such code where i want to save my best model in  given directory, so directory name in google colab is

```
path ='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/BTU_Training2020/Weights/weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5'
```

and i am writing following code at the end of keras model to keep and save best model :

```
checkpoint =ModelCheckpoint(filepath=path,monitor='val_accuracy',verbose=1,save_best_only=True,mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
model.fit(X,y,validation_split=0.33,epochs=150,batch_size=10,callbacks=callbacks_list,verbose=0)
```

it runs fine and shows me some  comments like this

```
Epoch 00001: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.55512, saving model to /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/BTU_Training2020/Weights/weights-improvement-01-0.56.hdf5

Epoch 00002: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.55512

Epoch 00003: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.55512

Epoch 00004: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.55512

Epoch 00005: val_accuracy improved from 0.55512 to 0.57087, saving model to /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/BTU_Training2020/Weights/weights-improvement-05-0.57.hdf5

Epoch 00006: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57087

Epoch 00007: val_accuracy improved from 0.57087 to 0.62598, saving model to /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/BTU_Training2020/Weights/weights-improvement-07-0.63.hdf5

Epoch 00008: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.62598
```

but when i see directory, there is not weight folder and  no file in each at all, could you please explain me what is reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ./ in your filepath.

This is assuming the folders you are trying to save to have already been created.

```
path ='./content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/BTU_Training2020/Weights/weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5'
```

Comment: still no  effect, maybe in a few minutes result will be clear

Comment: try this path ='./weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.h5' -- if that doesnt work then I dont think it is an issue with the filepath.. If the notebook is public do you have a link to the notebook?